# Does anyone know if raster operations are possible on a JavaFX Canvas graphics context?

Tags: canvas, javafx, xor, graphicscontext

This seems like a terrible oversight. In fact, I cannot continue development without a solution. I know it's possible to draw offscreen and transfer the image but I have a background on the canvas that I really cannot affect.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: "Raster operations" is a bit ambiguous to me.  Maybe you mean pixel manipulation through a [PixelWriter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/canvas/GraphicsContext.html#getPixelWriter--)?

Answer (score 0):

Canvases can be layered so I did that. Question withdrawn.